# Permission denied inspite of doing chmod 777

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, system-administration

```
(env3) ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/YoutubeCommentToWin$ sudo chmod -R 777 env3
(env3) ishandutta2007@MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/YoutubeCommentToWin$ pip3 install -U nltk
Collecting nltk
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in /Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/gleam/env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nltk) (1.11.0)
Installing collected packages: nltk
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/gleam/env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nltk'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Comment: what happened when you tried the '--user' option?

Comment: well I didnt do '--user' option, but doing sudo works, but that's not the point, point is what's wrong in above permission setting.